# MySQL: Selecting In Between DateTime records

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, join, crud

I want to get the count of records between two date-time entries.
I have a column in my table named `created_date` with the `datetime data type`.

I want to select rows which were created between `2017-01-10` and `2017-01-30`

I have written the following query but it doesn't seem to be inclusive

`SELECT* FROM table WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2017-01-10' AND '2017-01-30'`

Comment: There are no results between these dates. At least, none that we can see.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having has to do with that the date literal `2017-01-31` represents that date *at midnight*.  To get around this, phrase your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE created_date >= '2017-01-10' AND created_date < '2017-01-31';
```

This says to take any date on or after the very start of `2017-01-10` and *before* the start of `2017-01-31`.  This implies including the entire day `2017-01-30`.

Answer (score 0):

For get count of records between two date you can try below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tableName
WHERE date(created_date) >= '2017-01-10' AND date(created_date) <= '2017-01-30'
```

Comment: The OP's query is identical to what you wrote in your answer.

Comment: I don't think it's identical as `created` column converted in `DATE` from `DATETIME` and in this way it will include all the records from and to the date range. It will exclude `time` while comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM tableName
WHERE Cast(created_date as date) Between Cast('2017-01-10' as date) AND  Cast('2017-01-30' as date)
```

Comment: will it be inclusive?